# classCastException when sending multidimentioal arrayList in bundle

Tags: android, android-intent, multidimensional-array, arraylist, bundle

I have an app that parses a JSON object and put the data in a 2D ArrayList of type TwoDimentionalArrayList.

```
   public TwoDimentionalArrayList<String> getRota(String carerID, String date){


            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject1 = new JSONObject(tok3);

                int count = jsonObject1.names().length();




                for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){

                String s = new Integer(i).toString();

                 JSONObject jsonobject2 = (JSONObject) jsonObject1.get(s);
                 String startdate = jsonobject2.getString("StartDate");
                 String duration = jsonobject2.getString("Duration");
                 String callStatusName = jsonobject2.getString("CallStatusName");
                 String clientForeName = jsonobject2.getString("ClientForename");
                 String clientSurName = jsonobject2.getString("ClientSurname");
                 Log.e(TAG, "startdate = " + startdate);
                 Log.e(TAG, "duration = " + duration);
                 Log.e(TAG, "callStatusName = " + callStatusName);
                 Log.e(TAG, "clientForeName = " + clientForeName);
                 Log.e(TAG, "clientsurName = " + clientSurName);

                 ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
                 arr.add(startdate);
                 arr.add(duration);
                 arr.add(callStatusName);
                 arr.add(clientForeName);
                 arr.add(clientSurName);

                arrayList.add(i, arr);

                }

return arrayList;


    }// end of getRota

    class TwoDimentionalArrayList<T> extends ArrayList<ArrayList<T>> {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public void addToInnerArray(int index, T element) {
            while (index >= this.size()) {
                this.add(new ArrayList<T>());
            }
            this.get(index).add(element);
        }

        public void addToInnerArray(int index, int index2, T element) {
            while (index >= this.size()) {
                this.add(new ArrayList<T>());
            }

            ArrayList<T> inner = this.get(index);
            while (index2 >= inner.size()) {
                inner.add(null);
            }

            inner.set(index2, element);
        }
    }
```

.

I send the arryList in the following way.

```
                                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putSerializable("rotaArray", rotaArray);

                    intent.putExtra("rotaArrayBundle", b);
                    startActivity(intent);
```

And then retrieve it in another Activity like this.

```
intent = this.getIntent();
        Bundle bundle = intent.getBundleExtra("rotaArrayBundle");

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        TwoDimentionalArrayList<String> array = (TwoDimentionalArrayList<String>) bundle.get("rotaArray");
```

The app seems to have a problem casting the array to a TwoDimentionalArrayList which is an inner class of the one that parses the JSON. Here's the Exception.

```
09-20 11:23:13.797: E/AndroidRuntime(9743): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-20 11:23:13.797: E/AndroidRuntime(9743): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.carefreegroup/com.carefreegroup.GetRota}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to com.carefreegroup.LoginWebservice$TwoDimentionalArrayList
09-20 11:23:13.797: E/AndroidRuntime(9743):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2225)
09-20 11:23:13.797: E/AndroidRuntime(9743):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2260)
09-20 11:23:13.797: E/AndroidRuntime(9743):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:139)
09-20 11:23:13.797: E/AndroidRuntime(9743):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1277)
09-20 11:23:13.797: E/AndroidRuntime(9743):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-20 11:23:13.797: E/AndroidRuntime(9743):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
09-20 11:23:13.797: E/AndroidRuntime(9743):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5045)
09-20 11:23:13.797: E/AndroidRuntime(9743):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-20 11:23:13.797: E/AndroidRuntime(9743):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-20 11:23:13.797: E/AndroidRuntime(9743):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
09-20 11:23:13.797: E/AndroidRuntime(9743):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
09-20 11:23:13.797: E/AndroidRuntime(9743):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-20 11:23:13.797: E/AndroidRuntime(9743): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to com.carefreegroup.LoginWebservice$TwoDimentionalArrayList
09-20 11:23:13.797: E/AndroidRuntime(9743):     at com.carefreegroup.GetRota.onCreate(GetRota.java:27)
09-20 11:23:13.797: E/AndroidRuntime(9743):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4543)
09-20 11:23:13.797: E/AndroidRuntime(9743):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1071)
09-20 11:23:13.797: E/AndroidRuntime(9743):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2181)
09-20 11:23:13.797: E/AndroidRuntime(9743):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: `arrayList.add(i, arr);` Where does it declared?

Comment: @teoREtik as an instance variable of that class and instanciated in it's constructor

Comment: Do you declare it as `TwoDimentionalArrayList<String>`?

Comment: yes it's declared as that type

Comment: Just noticed that you haven't got any `catch` statement after `try` block and you build your project successfully?

Comment: thanks it's sorted now. I've posted an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed

```
TwoDimentionalArrayList<String> array = (TwoDimentionalArrayList<String>) bundle.get("rotaArray");
```

to

```
ArrayList array =  (ArrayList) bundle.get("rotaArray");

        Log.e(TAG, "array pos 0 = "+ array.get(0));
```

I can get the data now. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried implementing Serializable on your extended class?

```
class TwoDimentionalArrayList<T> extends ArrayList<ArrayList<T>> implements Serializable
```

Pass with

```
TwoDimentionalArrayList<?> tdlist = new TwoDimentionalArrayList<?>();
intent.putExtra("rotaArray", tdlist);
startActivity(intent);
```

Catch with

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
TwoDimentionalArrayList<?> tdlist = (TwoDimentionalArrayList) intent.getSerializableExtra("rotaArray");
```